# Problem with large amount of files uploading on a S3 bucket

Tags: ftp, amazon-s3

I have about 320.000 files i want to upload to a S3 bucket. Every software I tried took either a great deal of time, crashed, used up a greater deal of memory or just timed-out.

Is there a way to upload an archived file to the bucket and extract it while it's there?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider AWS Import/Export?
http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/

It is a way for you to just mail them a storage device so they can handle the import. The cost starts at $80 per device.